# Computer freezes when trying to go to sleep

Tags: suspend, shutdown, freeze

When I try to put my computer (a laptop: Asus X510UA) into sleep, usually, it works and I am able to wake it up correctly after. However, from time to time, I have a strange error: when I press the sleep button, the screen goes dark, but the computer remains active: the power LED is on and I can hear the fan spinning. At this point, I can not do anything: everything is frozen. Even `Alt+Fn+REISUB` doesn't seem to do anything. The only way to restart the computer is to press the power button for a long time.

It has happened for quite a long time (even before I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04).

Here is the part of `journalctl` juste before the going to sleep (I don't think there is anything suspicious):

```
oct. 09 00:18:23 [redacted]-X510UA systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
oct. 09 00:18:23 [redacted]-X510UA systemd[1]: Starting grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB...
oct. 09 00:18:23 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1696803503.718:1357): pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="d>
                                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:23 [redacted]-X510UA audit[913]: USER_AVC pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path=">
                                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:23 [redacted]-X510UA systemd[1]: Reached target sleep.target - Sleep.
oct. 09 00:18:23 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1696803503.690:1356): pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="d>
                                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:23 [redacted]-X510UA audit[913]: USER_AVC pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path=">
                                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:23 [redacted]-X510UA update-notifier[4191]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
oct. 09 00:18:23 [redacted]-X510UA wpa_supplicant[1013]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
oct. 09 00:18:23 [redacted]-X510UA wpa_supplicant[1013]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
oct. 09 00:18:23 [redacted]-X510UA wpa_supplicant[1013]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1696803502.970:1355): pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="d>
                                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA wpa_supplicant[1013]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA audit[913]: USER_AVC pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path=">
                                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA wpa_supplicant[1013]: p2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA wpa_supplicant[1013]: p2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA vmnet-natd[2372]: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp2s0 index:2 flags:0x00001002
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA vmnetBridge[2099]: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp2s0 index:2 flags:0x00001002
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA NetworkManager[997]: <info>  [1696803502.9191] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA NetworkManager[997]: <info>  [1696803502.9171] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: userif-3: sent link up event.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: userif-3: sent link down event.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA systemd-resolved[840]: wlp2s0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA avahi-daemon[910]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA avahi-daemon[910]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 10.150.0.64.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA avahi-daemon[910]: Withdrawing address record for 10.150.0.64 on wlp2s0.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA systemd-resolved[840]: wlp2s0: Bus client set default route setting: no
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA vmnet-natd[2372]: RTM_DELADDR: index:2, addr:10.150.0.64
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA systemd-resolved[840]: wlp2s0: Bus client reset search domain list.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA NetworkManager[997]: <info>  [1696803502.8445] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed no lease
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA NetworkManager[997]: <info>  [1696803502.8444] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA NetworkManager[997]: <info>  [1696803502.8443] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA avahi-daemon[910]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA avahi-daemon[910]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::6812:fc80:9123:7623.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA avahi-daemon[910]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::6812:fc80:9123:7623 on wlp2s0.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA wpa_supplicant[1013]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-9999 noise=9999 txrate=0
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA NetworkManager[997]: <info>  [1696803502.8106] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'manage>
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA wpa_supplicant[1013]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA wpa_supplicant[1013]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=ec:58:ea:3a:a5:0c reason=3 locally_generated=1
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA vmnet-natd[2372]: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp2s0 index:2 flags:0x00001003
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA vmnetBridge[2099]: Stopped bridge wlp2s0 to virtual network 0.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA vmnetBridge[2099]: Removing interface wlp2s0 index:2
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: wlp2s0: deauthenticating from ec:58:ea:3a:a5:0c by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA vmnetBridge[2099]: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlp2s0 index:2 flags:0x00001003
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA dbus-daemon[913]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1696803502.590:1354): pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="d>
                                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1696803502.590:1353): pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="d>
                                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1696803502.590:1352): pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="d>
                                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA dbus-daemon[913]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' reque>
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA audit[913]: USER_AVC pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path=">
                                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA audit[913]: USER_AVC pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path=">
                                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA audit[913]: USER_AVC pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path=">
                                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1696803502.586:1351): pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="d>
                                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA audit[913]: USER_AVC pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path=">
                                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1696803502.578:1350): pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="d>
                                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA ModemManager[1015]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA NetworkManager[997]: <info>  [1696803502.5810] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA audit[913]: USER_AVC pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path=">
                                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA NetworkManager[997]: <info>  [1696803502.5805] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1696803502.574:1349): pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="d>
                                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA NetworkManager[997]: <info>  [1696803502.5788] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'm>
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA NetworkManager[997]: <info>  [1696803502.5786] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA audit[913]: USER_AVC pid=913 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path=">
                                                   exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA systemd-logind[941]: The system will suspend now!
oct. 09 00:18:22 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
oct. 09 00:18:16 [redacted]-X510UA kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
```

I have looked at many threads of users having similar problems without finding anything... Thank you for your help

[EDIT] Since the problem occurs quite frequently, I started to shut down my computer more often instead of putting it to sleep... and I noticed that the same problem occurs from time to time when shutting down: I click on the shut down button, I validate, the screen goes black... but the computer remains on (the LED are on, the fan keeps spinning). I did not find anything strange on the logs

[EDIT 2] I tried adding `acpi=force` to GRUB, it doesn't change anything

[EDIT 3] updating to the last version of Ubuntu didn't change anything

Comment: I think this answer can help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/633851/64645

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not really my problem: the answer is about hibernation and not sleep. Also, my computer usually goes to sleep well, the issue occurs only from time to time

Comment: Is there any application running while you are shutting down your system??